# How to Create a CGSize in Swift?

Tags: swift

How can I create a CGSize in Swift? This is what I have tried so far (but doesn't work):

```
var s:CGSize = {10,20}
var s:CGSize = CGMakeSize(10,20)
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Your first attempt won't work because C structs don't exist in Swift. You need:

```
let size = CGSize(width: 20, height: 30)
```

Or (before Swift 3 only, and even then, not preferred):

```
let size = CGSizeMake(20,30)
```

(Not MakeSize).

Comment: IIRC, the docs recommend the first way rather than the Objective-C convenience methods.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Named parameters are also much nicer.

Comment: @Machado the answer already works in Swift 3, what do you mean? let vs var is nothing to do with the Swift version

Comment: The problem is `let size = CGSizeMake(20,30)`. The method `CGSizeMake` is unavailable in Swift.

Comment: Fair enough, I've added a comment in the answer

Answer (score 33):

As of Swift 3 you can no longer use `CGSizeMake`

The solution for Swift 3 is `var size = CGSize(width: 20, height: 30)`

Comment: they should say that instead of "CGSizeMake is unavailable in Swift" > this is misleading