# UISegmentedControl change the font of ONE segment

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uisegmentedcontrol, uifont

How can I change the font of ONE segment in a UISegmentedControl?

I know how to do it for the entire control.  But I want to highlight one segment if the user has something there.  However this one is NOT selected.

Note: I'm using swift 3

Thanks!

Comment: You will have to build your own interface.  This is not how SegmentedControl works.

Comment: You can subclass UISegementedControl and add whatever customisation you like.

Comment: You might need to use images for segment in such case

Comment: Yes I agree, this is what I'm trying now.  I will put up the code when I have it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the comments were right.  I needed an image for that segment.  I cobbled together some answers to get this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

        //custom funct to determine the index / just use your index
        guard let segIndexL = self.navMode?.determineIndexForMode(navType: navType) else {

            return
        }


        let width: CGFloat  =  29.0               
        let height: CGFloat = 24.0 //height (28) minus 2pt border for top and bottom
        let size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)


        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)

        var fontSize: CGFloat? = nil

        for segment in self.segSubViewNavControl.subviews {
            for label in segment.subviews {
                if label is UILabel {
                    fontSize = (label as! UILabel).font.pointSize + 1.0;
                    break
                }

                if fontSize != nil {
                    break
                }
            }   
        }

        guard let fontSizeL = fontSize else {
            return
        }

        let font  = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: fontSizeL)

        let txtAttributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName : font,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.red
        ] as [String : Any]

        guard let titleL = self.segSubViewNavControl.titleForSegment(at: segIndexL) else {
            return
        }

        let stringSizeL = titleL.size(attributes: txtAttributes)

        let rectText = CGRect(x: (width - stringSizeL.width) / 2, y: (height - stringSizeL.height) / 2, width: stringSizeL.width, height: stringSizeL.height)


        titleL.draw(
            in: rectText,
            withAttributes: txtAttributes
        )

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        self.segSubViewNavControl.setImage(newImage, forSegmentAt: segIndexL)


    })
```

I got these answers from here:

[iOS Drawing text in the centre of shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260314/ios-drawing-text-in-the-centre-of-shapes)

[How to make text appear in centre of the image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629118/how-to-make-text-appear-in-centre-of-the-image)

[How to Create a CGSize in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680701/how-to-create-a-cgsize-in-swift)

[How do I add text to an image in iOS Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906914/how-do-i-add-text-to-an-image-in-ios-swift)

[Using isKindOf in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37855734/using-iskindof-in-swift-3)

Thanks!